# How to find the ascii values of the characters in string?

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert characters in string into ascii value in Python

Like ord('a[i]') but ord expects only character not string!!

Is there any other method to solve this problem in python .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> s = "string"
>>> map(ord, s)
[115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103]
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to Sven's answer:

```
[ord(c) for c in s]
```

... or the corresponding generator expression:

```
(ord(c) for c in s)
```

Comment: +1 I prefer to use list comprehensions to `map` where possible

Comment: @Alasdair when would it ever *not* be possible?

Comment: @Alasdair Comprehension is great if you'd have to create lambda (or normal function) and/or use `filter` as addition to the `map`. But when you are just calling existing function (for example `int`) it's (in my opinion) more cleaner and readable to use map. And according to my simple measurement I just did it's faster.